# Running UWP on Web Browser Like Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

In the past, I used **Silverlight** for creating the **WPF** - like apps for web. Now, I'am developing a new app and it's prototype is on **UWP**. Can I run it as a Web app on any browser like Silverlight ?Is there any plugin like that for uwp? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no you can't. UWP is for the windows platform like desktop. although there are some interesting projects going on based on web assembly with c# and xaml

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the Uno Platform: https://platform.uno/

You can even try it out live here: https://playground.platform.uno/

Performance for the Web Assembly is still being worked on though.  That's due to the work needed in the Mono dependency here: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/10222

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check Blazor ( www.blazor.net )